# Loading bootstrap3 menu items from json response

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to show items send from server as bootstreap munu items.
For that I an trying following code

*HTML*

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown"> <span id="info-count"></span>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="get-info-list">
            <i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="infolist" role="menu">
            <!--Items should be loaded here-->
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

*Script*

```
$(document).on('click', '#get-info-list', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('hiiiiiii');
    $.getJSON('getNotification', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#infolist").append(data);
    });
});
```

I am trying here to load data in `li` as menu items.
I tried this code here http://jsfiddle.net/b0ws91e2
click event is not working on click on `get-info-list`.
How to make it work??
Is above is proper way to load json response or bootstreap menu provide any simple way to load data dynamically?

Comment: you need to decode the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write you js code in ready event like this

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#get-info-list').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('hiiiiiii');
        $.getJSON('getNotification', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#infolist").append(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Reference http://jsfiddle.net/b0ws91e2/4/

**Explanation:** The reason is that your code is being executed when javascript files and code is being loaded but you web page DOM is not ready, so it is not registering event on any specific component. So you need to wait till DOM get ready, so now this code will be executed when DOM is ready

Comment: I changed the code `id="get-info-list"` with `<a>`.  No On click the <a> I want to call jquery method but this is not doning so.

Comment: didnt get the alert message

Comment: Register event like this -> $('#get-info-list').on('click', function(event) { 
I have updated the answer aswell

Comment: Cool, what was the change in my suggestion?