# $(document).on('click', .... is not working on file inclusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `header.jsp` file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("calling in header");
    $(document).on('click', '#get-info-list', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('hiiiiiii');
        $.get('getNotification', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#infolist").append(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Some where in code

```
 <li class="dropdown">
    <span id="info-count"></span>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="get-info-list">
        <i class="fa fa-list-alt" ></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="infolist" role="menu">
    </ul>
</li>
```

I have a `test.jsp` file where in header div id i have added above `header.jsp`

```
<div id="header">
   <jsp:include page="/pages/common/header.jsp"/>
</div>
```

Here I am running `test.jsp` file script on `header.jsp` is excecuting and
showing alert `calling in header` but it is not calling method below it.
On console also it is not printing any error.

what may be the problem??
How to resolve this??

I asked the related problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951482/loading-bootstrap3-menu-items-from-json-response). It is [working properly](http://jsfiddle.net/b0ws91e2/3/) on same file.
But on my system this is not working.

Comment: Try to wrap your ``click`` event inside a function and add ``onclick="functionName(event)"`` to your ``get-info-list`` element and see what happens.

Comment: is there any other library which is not jquery? that could override the `$` function ?

Comment: @JuniusRendel as long as first alert is showing, I think it's all good.

Comment: Its generally a good idea to have your javascript included at the bottom of the page just before the end body tag - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638670/javascript-at-bottom-top-of-web-page - also why are you including javascript as a jsp file?and why like that and not in the regular way -  
`<script src="/pages/common/header.js"></script>`

Comment: @Craicerjack I have included in header

Comment: @TanseButcaru except if it is overriden after his code, the `$(document).ready()` could work fine and the `$` be overriden after  it was called, depending on `<script>` tags order...

Comment: I edited my answer, take a look at it...

Comment: @xrcwrn Okay but why are you including it as a jsp file? Why not just include it as a regular js file?

Comment: I have create header file seperatle and its js code is also there

Comment: do you get any errros/messages in console when clicking that element?

Comment: did you try any answer here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap your click event inside a function and add `onclick="functionName(event)"` to your `get-info-list` element and see what happens.

JS:

```
    function clickMe(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        alert('hiiiiiii');
        $.get('getNotification', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#infolist").append(data);
        });
    }
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="get-info-list" onclick="clickMe(event)">
```

If your code is working on same file, then I guess that you're loading the html file/those elements later on page (via ajax request for eg), so all the bindings will not be available for those elements because they don't exists when the script is loading.

Answer (score 0):

If another library uses the dollar sign, it will override it if that library is included after the `$(document).ready()` call, you can safely use the `$` parameter passed by `$(document).ready()` like this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
   $(document).on('click', '#get-info-list', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('hiiiiiii');
            $.get('getNotification', function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#infolist").append(data);
            });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code will not execute unless you'll specify script tags, add your js code inside script tag in your header.jsp.

Thanks